# Bash script to start java spring boot application from SSH

Tags: bash, java, nohup

I have a simple bash script file, which is triggered from pipeline job ( via SSH ).
The **deploy.sh** contains more or less something like this:

```
cd /apps && java -jar "-Dspring.profiles.active=prod " "-Dserver.port=$PORT " \
"/apps/$DEPLOYING_VERSION" &
```

And some other logic which is not so important.
The pipeline via SSH executes:

```
bash /deploy.sh ${APPLICATION_NAME}
```

How to start **deploy.sh** in order the java -jar to be executed and separated from the **deploy.sh** in order my pipeline (job) to finish and in the same time, the java app to continue working on the machine?
I tried with

```
cd /apps && nohup java -jar "-Dspring.profiles.active=prod " "-Dserver.port=$PORT " \
"/apps/$DEPLOYING_VERSION" &
```

But the job stuck...

It will be cool to track and the exit from the java -jar, but it is not so important right now :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run in parallel `cd /apps` and `java -jar` you should use a single ampersand, not two:  `cd /apps & java -jar`. However, the `java -jar` command will not work if it assumes it is run within the /apps directory.

More in general, `command1 & command2` will run command1 and command2 independently, in parallel.

Note that your CI/CD tool (assuming you're talking about CI/CD pipelines) may support running tasks in parallel, so you could also try to solve this issue in the pipeline definition, if this makes sense in your case.

Comment: Thank you for the info, but my problem is that the CI/CD job is not terminating because of the java -jar which starts a web server.. I separete the cd /apps and java -jar to be different commands, but it is the same..

I want to start the java -jar, and to exit the deploy.sh script in order to finish the Ci/CD and in the same time java -jar to continue working on the server

Comment: If that is the case, you could run nohup and find a way to exit. For example: nohup <something> &> /dev/null

Comment: I've tried ... still no success :( 
nohup java -jar "-Dspring.profiles.active=prod " "-Dserver.port=$PORT " \
"/apps/$DEPLOYING_VERSION" &> /dev/null

Comment: Somehow ... eveyrhing works with:
cd /apps;
nohup java -jar "-Dspring.profiles.active=prod " "-Dserver.port=$PORT " \
"/apps/$DEPLOYING_VERSION" > /apps/spring.log 2>&1 &

Answer (score 0):

```
cd /apps;
nohup java -jar "-Dspring.profiles.active=prod " "-Dserver.port=$PORT " \
"/apps/$DEPLOYING_VERSION" > /apps/spring.log 2>&1 &
```

Makes the magic.